# Confused about how to compile modsecurity module for apache in Ubuntu 14

Tags: command-line, apache2, compiling, c

After I followed the instructions in *Building Custom ModSecurity Modules* section in [modsecurity dev guide](http://www.modsecurity.org/developers.html) in order to compile `mod_tfn_reverse.c` using the command `apxs -ca mod_tfn_reverse.c`, I'm still finding "fatal errors" such as `unable to find the file modsecurity.h` mentioned in the header of the C document.

Here is the link to the source on [Github](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity).

**Instructions I did:**

1. I am using Ubuntu 14.4 64bits (New installation with updates).
2. I installed `apache-dev` package, to run `apxs` command on terminal.
3. I Downloaded `modsecurity` zip file from github.
4. I extracted the zip file, then I located where the `mod_tfn_reverse.c` is.

   Its path: `ModSecurity/ext/mod_tfn_reverse.c`
5. Then I changed the directory to the targeted file CD modsecurity/ext as I placed the folder in "home".
6. Finally, I executed the command `apxs -ca mod_tfn_reverse.c`.

These are the instructions I did, `apxs` works, but the compilation fails because `modsecurity.h` declared in the header was not found, I searched this file I found it in another directory (`ModSecurity/apache2/modsecurity.h`).

So, the difficulty is, how can I successfully compile that specific file and have the module done and ready to use in apache2 server. I am also confused about what are the other archives, headers, and development tools required to:

1. to compile a custom apache module (This is my main goal).
2. to compile `mod_tfn_reverse.c`, in my case, knowing that this is only the starting point to create custom module for modsecurity.

Thanks,

Comment: also, if you don't get an answer you can try here: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I created an account there and I will repost my question in case no answer right here. Thanks again

Comment: you say the compilation fails, where does it fail? did you cd into the top direcrory and run `./autogen.sh`

Comment: then, did you run `./configure` and then `make`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that, I moved to top directory, and I ran ./autogen.sh, I didn't know what it is for, but it said that I don't have the permission.

Comment: The compilation fails by the include line of modsecurity.h.
I think, the problem is a whole procedure must be taken all step by step.
and I still don't have it yet

Comment: you should not have downloaded the zip file, you should follow the instructions and use the command `git clone https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity.git`

Comment: then, `cd ModSecurity` will take you to the top level directory

Comment: Thank you @mchid for these instructions, will try now these.

Comment: please post any errors

Comment: Until now, I Installed "apache2", "apr1.5.2", "apr-util1.54" ,"libpcre"and "libxml2" which are the prequisites.  I installed also "git", and I am (ready) to access the modsecurity github repository.

In the guide `$cp /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/mod_security2.so /usr/local/apache/modules/`, In my case I find apache2 was installed in `/etc/apache2/` is that ok if the location is different or something is missing ? 

Have a look:
`ls /etc/apache2/

apache2.conf    conf-enabled  magic           mods-enabled  sites-available
conf-available  envvars       mods-available  ports.conf    sites-enabled`

Comment: you have to run `sudo cp /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/mod_security2.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/` because that is where it usually installs when you install `libapache2-mod-security2` in ubuntu

Comment: I did this:
1- `git clone git://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity.git`
2- `cd ModSecurity`
3- `sudo ./autogen.sh` here I had to install more packages (libtoolize|autoconf|autoheader|automake). then I reexecuted `./autogen.sh` and it worked well.
4- `sudo ./configure` here I meet another error, "libxml2 is missing" but I already installed it before and I checked it with "synaptic package manager" and it is there, I reinstalled it in command line and repeated the procedure again and ./configure stops and ask for libxml2.
[capturescreen link](http://jpst.it/Ba3o)

Comment: The dependencies must be installed I only installed libxml2 as it is mentioned in the installation guide  but there is one more thing in order to complete the installation and generate *.so file.
`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` and the installation completed very well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally did  compile "ModSecurity" apache module on ubuntu 14.4 and have had the *.so file.
Well, All what I have done is to install the  dependencies that the installation shell can't find.

1. Download APR1.5.2 zip file
2. CD APR1.5.2
3. sudo ./configure
4. make
5. make test
6. sudo make install (It wasn't allowed for me to install without sudo)

The system needed "curl" so I installed it.
**git installation and clone ModSecurity:**

1. `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `git clone git://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity.git`

After I failed couple of times to install it!
I explored that a number of libraries must be installed first
libtoolize|autoconf|automake|autoheader|libxml2-dev
`sudo apt-get install build essential libtool libxml2-dev autoconf automake autoheader`

And you are ready to go.

1. cd into the directory - $`cd ModSecurity`
2. Run autogen.sh script - $`./autogen.sh`
3. Run configure script - $`./configure`
4. Run make - $`make`
5. Run make install - $`make install`

You will find it in this path `/usr/local/modsecurity/lib/mod_security2.so`.

Thanks,